# How to locate a specific child of a specific level2 node in a nested set

Tags: sql, nested-sets

I have a standard nested set model with each node having name, lft & rgt attributes.

I can find the superiors of a specific employee using:

```
SELECT P2.* FROM Personnel AS P1, Personnel AS P2
WHERE P1.lft BETWEEN P2.lft AND P2.rgt
AND P1.name = "Bob"
ORDER BY P2.lft
```

I can also find the level2 manager by adding limit & offset:

```
SELECT P2.* FROM Personnel AS P1, Personnel AS P2
WHERE P1.lft BETWEEN P2.lft AND P2.rgt
AND P1.name = "Bob"
ORDER BY P2.lft
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1
```

In some situations I may have multiple employees called "Bob" working under different level2 managers. The level2 manager names are unique.

I need a query that returns all the employees called "Bob" for the level2 manager called "Susan".

Edit: My query needs to return only the "Bob that works under "Mary" as he is the only one with a level2 manager called "Susan".

```
   Big Boss
   /      \
Brian   Susan
  |       |
Susan   Mary
  |       |
 Bob     Bob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the numbers in:

```
  1 Big Boss 14
   /        \
2 Brian 7  8 Susan 13
  |           |
3 Susan 6  9 Mary 12
  |           |
4 Bob 5    10 Bob 11
```

If we can specify that we know that its the "Susan" at `8` then:

```
SELECT employee.* 
FROM Personnel AS employee
inner join Personnel AS manager on employee.lft BETWEEN manager.lft
                                                    AND manager.rgt
WHERE 
  employee.name = 'Bob'
  and manager.name = 'Susan'
  and manager.lft = 8
ORDER BY employee.lft
```

Otherwise, I think you need to know more about the record to specify which manager you're speaking of.

EDIT: Making the query a bit more complicated, I've calculated depth using suggestions from [this article](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2013/01/tree-in-sql-database-nested-set-model.html).  The **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc0d9/11)** for this is working as well.

```
select
  employee.*
from
  Personnel employee
  inner join 
    (SELECT node.name, node.lft, node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
     FROM Personnel AS node
     inner join Personnel AS parent on node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
     GROUP BY node.name, node.lft, node.rgt) as manager
                 on employee.lft between manager.lft and manager.rgt    
where
  employee.name = 'bob'
  and manager.name = 'susan'
  and manager.depth = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much however this returns both Bobs from the tree whereas I need to be specific to the one with Susan at level2.

Comment: Never used fiddle before so I hope this is right. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc0d9/1

Comment: As Susan at level2 is unique I was hoping to be able to simply specify the name only.

Comment: You might consider adding a `level` column as in [this example](https://wiki.easyvista.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/Nested+sets)  Then you could just say `where manager.level = 2 and manager.name = 'susan'`

Comment: Another idea is to take big boss.rgt - 1 to set your second level.

Comment: Future will have others so hard coding the lft or rgt doesn't work :(

Comment: @user1567212, what about full names instead of just first names?

Comment: Also, you dont mention what DBMS you are using.  You used the default MySQL on the fiddle, are you using mysql?