# How to search for a specific child when you know the parent?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tree, nested-sets

I have a standard nested set model with each node having ID, name, owner, lft and rgt attributes. Given an inputted path, such as this:

> //components/core/build/src/

I want to search for the file

> src

that has a parent named

> build

Here is how the tree looks

```
   components
       |      
     core   
       |      
    build   
     /  \  
 src     1.0
          |
         src
```

**How can I query the specific src with a specific parent using mySQL?**

This is the query I have now:

```
SELECT parent.file_id, parent.owner, parent.name 
FROM file_category AS node, file_category AS parent 
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
AND node.name = 'src'
```

This returns something close to what I want. If the tree didn't have duplicates, it would work.

It returns the attributes of every node of the tree until it reaches src. However, since there are two 'src' nodes, it returns their common ancestors twice and then will branch off and return the attributes from the distinct ancestors of each 'src'.

So the table returned looks like this:

```
owner   name
dez     components
dez     components
sam     core
sam     core
tom     build
tom     build
mai     src
jim     1.0
bob     src
```

It will return their common ancestors twice.

I thought to try this:

```
SELECT parent.file_id, parent.owner, parent.name
FROM file_category AS node, file_category AS parent 
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
AND node.name = 'src' AND parent.name = 'build'
```

But this returns a table with two build rows. Perhaps because they both share a common ancestor of build?

I tried this as well but got the same result as the query above:

```
SELECT parent.file_id, parent.owner, parent.name
FROM file_category AS node, file_category AS parent 
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
AND node.name = 'src' AND parent.name = 'build' AND parent.lft = 3
```

Also, I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983613/how-to-locate-a-specific-child-of-a-specific-level2-node-in-a-nested-set) which is very close to my question, however, the answer provided didn't work.

I'm new to SQL, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have a UNIQUE identifier for the parent, you don't really "know" the parent.

Comment: I do have a file_id. I forgot to add that. Let me edit the question.

Comment: What are the lft are rgt attributes? My first intuition was they were some sort of first and last child id values, but you'd have to be doing a decent amount of work to enforce such a constraint in a meaningful manner; and I am not sure why offhand you would be using `node.lft BETWEEN` instead of `node.file_id BETWEEN`.

Comment: My tree is based off the nested set bit of this article: [link] (http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) Everything is pretty much the same except I have a field called "owner". If you scroll down to the section named "Retrieving a Single Path" under Nested Set Model, that is where I got this SQL query from. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I've only really worked with that author calls the adjacency model. It is surprisingly hard to get a group of developers to follow a child_id > parent_id constraint, I'd dread trying to enforce that kind of structure.

Comment: Perhaps this option is not available to you, but it seems adding a `depth` field to your db schema would make this much easier. Alternatively, since you appear to have unique ids on your nodes, you might even be able to `LEFT JOIN` a depth subquery without touching your schema. Then it's essentially `BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt  AND node.depth = parent.depth+1`. Although I'm not familiar enough with this model to turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this is my solution as per my understanding of your schema

```
SELECT parent.file_id, parent.owner, parent.name
FROM file_category AS node, file_category AS parent 
WHERE (node.file_id = parent.lft OR node.file_id = parent.rgt) 
AND node.name = 'src';
```